# Issue with installing dependent plugins from the command line

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, command-line, eclipse-juno

We are trying to install a set of eclipse plugins from the commandline.

First we need to install ADT plugin.

Then we are trying to install a plugin which dependent on the ADT plugin.

The installation of the dependent plugin is failing with an error:

`Missing requirement: "OurPluginName" ("Ourplugin.feature.group") requires 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 11.0.0' but it could not be found`

We are using the following command to install a plugin from the commandline:

`eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository [our-update-side] -installIU [our.feature.group] -destination "[eclipse-install-directory]"`

We observed the following:

If we only install the ADT plugin then start the eclipse IDE in UI mode, stop it again and perform afterwards an installation of the plugin which is dependent on the ADT plugin, the above error is not occurring.

So the question is now: How can we install the dependent plugin via command line without starting the ecilpse IDE manual.

Do you know a way how to update the eclipse repository from the command line?

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards

Frank

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved :-):

Do it in the following way:

1. Download the ZIP File containing the ADT plugin, don't download it via the update side!
2. Extract the ZIP-File content in your eclipse folder.
3. Now you can install additional plugins dependent from the ADT plugin as described above.

Hope this helps you too.

Best Regards

Frank